# Log precision in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is sourcecode which checks that wether a number can be expressed in power but why does the code fail for `n = 76 ** 89 - 1` and `n = 76 ** 89`. How can I solve this error? For both n it gives `x=log(n,2)/log(i,2)=89.0`

```
from math import log,sqrt,floor
import sys
n= 76 ** 89 - 1
t=floor(sqrt(n))+1
flag=False


for i in range(2,t):
    x=log(n,2)/log(i,2)
    print(x)
    if x-int(x)<sys.float_info.epsilon:
        print("YESSSSSSSSSSSSS!")
        flag=True
        break

if not flag:
    print("Nooooooooooooooooooo!")
```

Comment: nice, but a real [mcve] isn't interactive. How are we supposed to enter `76  ** 89 - 1` since python 3 input doesn't perform evaluations?

Comment: @Jean 
246836689407345097174578535562295942574178711461144990797750214379645671228733039816084061952588114546106170632976745994369878558718869787931874388378698664981274034176 and 246836689407345097174578535562295942574178711461144990797750214379645671228733039816084061952588114546106170632976745994369878558718869787931874388378698664981274034175

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are just showing the tail of your actual problem.

Comment: As you've discovered, floating-point is not sufficient for these calculations, in general.  You may make some headway by doing a sanity check once you've identified a candidate - compute `i**x` and see if it matches the original value.

Comment: @user1767754 - The user seems to have been fairly explicit about their aim - to write a program that determines whether an integer is an exact power.

Comment: I was looking into something similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476802/is-there-a-mapping-function-to-transform-mn-to-sum-i-in-k2i-any-powe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only finds candidates but doesn't check if they *really* match. 
Floating point inaccuracy makes that you cannot make the difference between a very big value like this and this same value minus one.

But since python has built-in unlimited range integer artihmetic, you could *check* that what you found is really a match.

My idea: once you find the power, compute the theoretical number to power (by rounding), then compute power in integer, and compare integers.

```
from math import log,sqrt,floor
import sys
n = 76 ** 89
t=floor(sqrt(n))+1
flag=False


for i in range(2,t):
    x=log(n,i)  # faster than x=log(n,2)/log(i,2)

    if x-int(x)<sys.float_info.epsilon:
        x = int(round(x))
        r = int(round(n**(1/x)))
        print("found candidate: ",x,r)
        if n == r**x:   # exact integer comparison with initial value & found values
            print("YESSSSSSSSSSSSS!")
            flag=True
            break
        else:
            print("but not exact")

if not flag:
    print("Nooooooooooooooooooo!")
```

with the `76 ** 89 - 1` value, you get "but not exact" because the computed power doesn't match `n` value.

Aside: it's faster to use `x=log(n,i)` instead of `x=log(n,2)/log(i,2)` and probably more accurate too as less float operations are involved.

Comment: Good stuff.  But I can't convince myself that the floating-point limitations won't also be susceptible to false negatives.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth maybe we'll miss some with all the rounding which could go the wrong way (maybe it's what you're implying, still to find the cases) but the case we find are sure to work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I'm thinking about the original `log/log` calculation - is the `epsilon` threshold sufficient to accept the result for all exact powers?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that wouldn't hurt to specify a bigger epsilon. That would just be slower. another problem is that at some point `sqrt(n)` doesn't want to compute the square root: "OverflowError: int too large to convert to float". Interestingly, log works but not sqrt.

Comment: Q: Is `log(n, i)` better in terms of float point accuracy instead of `log(n, 2)/log(i, 2)`? I would expect that it is more accurate and faster.