# Wrong answer from math.log(python 3)

Tags: python, math

Today, I used `math.log()` function to get the logarithm of 4913 to the given base 17. The answer is 3, but when I ran the code below, I got 2.9999999999999996.

1) Is it because `math.log(x, b)`'s calculation is `log(x) / log(b)`?

2) Is there any solution to get the correct answer 3?

```
import math
print(math.log(4913,17))
```

Comment: Your conjecture (#1) is quite likely. As for #2, there are many methods. Do you know a priori that the answer will be an integer?

Comment: Better duplicate: [Log precision in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042460/log-precision-in-python)

Comment: @nwellnhof i reopened the question as the OP also wants to know how to get an integer solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) says so explicitly.
2. Another solution is to use the Decimal class, from the "decimal" library:

   ```
   import math
   from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
   getcontext().prec = 6
   Decimal(math.log(4913))/Decimal(math.log(17))
   ```

Comment: or `Decimal(4913).ln() / Decimal(17).ln()`

Answer (score 3):

you could use the [`gmpy2`](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```
import gmpy2

print(gmpy2.iroot(4913, 3))
# (mpz(17), True)

print(gmpy2.iroot(4913 + 1, 3))
# (mpz(17), False)
```

which tells you the result and whether or not it is exact.

also have a look at [Log precision in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042460/log-precision-in-python) and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!